# Why does it think my class arrays are default int arrays?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to create an array of class objects, then initialize each component individually. I manage to declare my class array easily:

Classsystem.h

```cpp
class RACE {

public:

    string name;
    string shortdescription;
    string description;
    int noobjects;
    bool objects[N];
    int agressiveness;
    bool hulls[nohulls];
    bool shields[noshields];
    bool weapons[noweapons];
    bool companies[nocompanies];
    double tax;
    double bank;
    double currency;
    int diplomacy[noraces];
    double population;

public:

    ~RACE(){}
    RACE() {
        name="Default Race";
        shortdescription="Default";
        description="Default";
        noobjects=0;
        for(int i=0; i<N;i++) { objects[i]=0; }
        agressiveness=0;
        for (int i=0; i<nohulls;i++) { hulls[i]=0 ; }
        for (int i=0; i<noshields;i++) { shields[i]=0; }
        for(int i=0; i<noweapons;i++) { weapons[i]=0; }
        for(int i=0; i<nocompanies;i++) { companies[i]=0; }
        tax=0;
        bank=0;
        currency=1;
    }

    RACE(string iname, int inoobjects, int iagressiveness, double itax, double ibank, double icurrency) {
        name=iname;
        noobjects=inoobjects;
        agressiveness=iagressiveness;
        tax=itax;
        bank=ibank;
        currency=icurrency;
        for(int i=0; i<N;i++) { objects[i]=0; } 
        for(int i=0; i<nohulls;i++) { hulls[i]=1; } 
        for(int i=0; i<noshields;i++) { shields[i]=1; }
        for(int i=0; i<noweapons;i++) { weapons[i]=1; } 
        for(int i=0; i<nocompanies;i++) { companies[i]=0; }
    }
};
```

races.h:

```cpp
 races[0].name="anything";
```

main.ccp:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Classsystem.h"

RACE races[16];

#include "races.h"

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
return 0;
}
```

the errors reads:

> races.h(1) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
>   races.h(1) : error C2143: syntax error : missing `';'` before `'.'`
>   races.h(1) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   races.h(1) : error C2371: `'races'` : redefinition; different basic types
>   control console.cpp(13) : see declaration of `'races'`

this still produces the error.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compiler tr[ies] to reassign it to a default int"?  What makes you think the compiler is doing that?  If you got a warning or error message, please show it (copy-and-paste it) as part of your question.

Comment: What does "the compiler tries to reassign it to a default int" mean?  Also, the most important bit of code you can provide is the bit that causes the error, and I don't see any `races` objects in your sample.

Comment: As a guess, though, you probably don't want `races[0]->name`, but rather `races[0].name`

Comment: edit: added errors chenged -> to . still have problem

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're using?  `RACE` is a class, so given `RACE races[16];`, `races[0]` is a class, not a pointer, and so needs `.` rather than `->`.  So, given invalid C++, you get an error that you describe as something I don't recognize.  Please recheck your code fragments, and describe what behavior you actually get.

Comment: iv changed the code and put the errors in and im having the same problem, u can see i am using the . in the code and its giving me that error. is there a limit to the number of header files in VS2008? any code i put into new headers seems to malfunction.

Comment: You are correct, @Gregory, we don't want to see the whole program. We want to see you reduce your program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates your problem. Then we want to see the whole of *that* program. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I still don't see any *actual* code generating the error.  I see a line, but no context.  Cut out any fluff, and provide the actual function causing this error.

Comment: What immediately precedes the fragment `races[0].name="anything";` ?

Comment: @Rob this line is the only thing left after i commented out the rest in this header file. imeadiatly before the include is the decloration of races. and imeadiatly before that is the include for my class system and all the other classes are working fine and the RACE class is at the top of that header. ill try commenting them out.

Comment: Now, if you just added in which line each error appears...

Comment: iv minimized the code and put the error lines in, thanks for all this.

Comment: @GregoryAuton: The wild guess is confirmed with the last edit. You cannot write code at namespace level, and it makes even less sense to put it in a header that needs to be inserted *after* adding other code... I guess you now realize the value of providing the actual code, the answer would have taken just a few seconds if you had done this from the beginning. [Also, I changed the tag, this is not C++, but C++-CLI, and they are completely different languages in case you wonder why I changed it. The code above would not compile in any C++ compiler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with my crystal ball, I am going to go for a wild guess to explain the errors:

```
1. error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
2. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
3. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
4. error C2371: 'races' : redefinition; different basic types
\control console.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'races'
```

And the guess is that:

```
races[0].name = "anything";
```

is at namespace level, outside of any function. The language does not allow you to add code at namespace level, and the compiler is getting confused. It is trying to match that against patterns for *valid* and is considering that `races[0]` is a declaration of an array of `0` elements (error 1) of *implicit type* `int` (C allowed the type specifier to be skipped in a declaration, and would default to `int` there --error 3). If that is a declaration, it must be followed by either `;` or `,` but the compiler is reading a `.`, so it believes that to belong to the next expression, and that there should be a `;` before it (error 2). Finally the whole declaration redefines the variable `races` to be an array of 0 `int`, while the first definition makes it an array of 16 `RACE` (error 4).

Comment: would putting RACE in a namespace fix this?

Comment: No, moving the code *out* of namespace level will fix it, you cannot add code just anywhere, only inside functions, and then call those functions from other functions... that's how the language goes. If you just move that line of code inside `main` it should compile.

Comment: got ya! chears mate forgot i was including outside my main. ur a ledge

Comment: @GregoryAuton: *I was including outside my main* seems to indicate that you are happy with having that piece of code in a header and including it from `main`. Don't. While it will work --`#include` just performs text substitution of that line with the included file-- it is against all known idioms and code patterns, which means that it will be hard to read by others, and won't help you learning the proper way of doing things.

Comment: ok thanks im self taught by trial and error so ill go and learn some code patterns. i have alot of code i was going to put into my races array, i only wanted to keep my main neet and tidy. ill used a load file and funtion to store all the filein's etc, is that better code?

Comment: @GregoryAuton: you usually declare functions (or types or what not) in headers, and then provide the implementations of those functions in .cpp files that you compile and link together. If you want to keep your `main` tidy, move the code to a function and then call it from main. I would recommend that you follow some tutorial or introductory book to learn the basics.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the compiler error says (you should add it to the question), but this is wrong:

```
races[0]->name="anything";
```

`races[0]` is an object of type `RACE`, not a pointer, which means that to update the `name` you do not use `->`, but rather `.`:

```
races[0].name = "anything";
```

Comment: true that was a typo putting it in here =P

Comment: Typos in code aren't an issue if you copy-and-paste the *exact* code that you fed to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For a class named `RACE`, an array of `RACE races[16]` would be accessed with `races[0].name = "anything"`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler says it doesn't know what is RACE. Probably you forgot to include the header where it's declared.

EDIT:

Something like this:

```
#include "race.h"

RACE races[16];
```

Comment: iv got the include header after the decloration which is just after the class header include, is that not right?

Comment: i got:

    #include "Classsystem.h"

then:

RACE races[16];

then:

    #include "races.h"

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question but I think it's assuming int because the definition of the class failed because of previous errors which you will need to fix first.

Comment: possible but im only getting those 4 errors and i dont have any if i just declare the array and do nothing with it and the program works fine again.

Comment: @GregoryAuton Now that you've added the line numbers I can see that they aren't actually previous errors at all.